# separate integers in row with commas?

Tags: java, numbers, row

I feel like there is a simple way to do this but i'm trying to separate the numbers in this row with commas except the last one(being 20).

```
public class ForLoops
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    final int MAX = 21;
  for (int row = 1; row<MAX; row++)
    System.out.print(row);
}
}
```

instead of displaying 123456789101112(ect.) i need it to display 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12(etc).
any advise?

Comment: Do you know how String concatenation works?

Comment: no i don't believe i've learned that yet

Comment: My comment was rhetorical. It was meant to give you keywords you can look up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int row = 1; row<MAX; row++) {
    System.out.print(row);
    if(row != MAX -1)
          System.out.print(",");

}
```

Comment: Missing a closing curly bracket.  Or you have an extra opening curly bracket, as your `if` is only a 1-liner.

Comment: @user2805461 Glad to help you out but did you noticed the curly brace as mentioned by nhgrif. Fixed it though.

Comment: if i wanted to add by 2 instead of 1 how would i go about that?

Comment: @user2805461 It would be better if you try it yourself. Its good for you. If you are stuck with problem, post another question, I'll follow along.

Answer (score 1):

One of the integers needs to be printed in a special way, since we have one less comma than numbers to "print".

I suggest printing the first number without a comma, then looping through the remaining numbers printing a comma *in front* of the number.

When you finish the loop, you will probably want to print a newline.